# How to config InternalsVisibleTo for PowerShell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, roslyn

I am maintaining an internal library. A lot of classes/methods are specified as internal access to avoid abusing.

But I also want to use these assemblies in PowerShell. But internal access allows only those assemblies explicitly marked as InternalsVisibleTo. So I wonder which assemblies need to be added for PowerShell scenario.

Or are there any Roslyn tricks can help my scenario?

Comment: Use a satellite assembly that exposes these internals (by wrapping them in public types/methods), grant that `InternalsVisibleTo`, and deploy the satellite assembly in a PowerShell module so only PowerShell has access. As a bonus, you now have a properly vetted API that you can version. The alternative is somehow finding out "the" assemblies used by PowerShell to grant those access, but this is very brittle -- it won't be stable across versions of PowerShell, and as a "bonus" you have no control over what gets exposed at all.

Comment: @jeroen Two many types/methods. It is a big effort to wrap them manually.